# Registering a HTTP-Interceptor in a lazy loaded Module

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

Good Morning,
I've run into a problem I seem to not be able to solve myself.

I'm trying to register a httpinterceptor in a different place than the initial config block.

Doing this works as expected:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
.config(function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
     return {
       request: function($request) {
         console.log($request);
         return $request;
       }
     }
   })
})
```

But the interceptor is part of a submodule. So my app looks as follows:

EDIT:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);
angular.module('app.submodule', ['ngResource'])
.config(function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
     return {
       request: function($request) {
         console.log($request);
         return $request;
       }
     }
   })
})
```

Additionally the submodule is lazyloaded. But I do not think that is the root of the problem.

I tried referencing the httpProvider in the initial config block by adding:

```
$httpProviderReference = $httpProvider;
```

So I could register an interceptor later. This wouldn't even work in the initial run() block. Inspecting the Provider, it seems to have worked, but the interceptor is never called.

Does anyone know how to work around this? I am trying to add an authentication token to the header of a request.

Thanks in advance, olu

Comment: are you sure angular.module('app.submodule', []) does what you think it does, to me it looks like it is just creating a new module and knows nothing about the other module.

Comment: i have added the dependency to ngResource to the submodule. is this what you've been referring to? when i try to register an interceptor in the main modules run method, it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else encountering a similar problem, this is how i have done it:

I registered a general interceptor in my main module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
.config(function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push('Interceptors');
})
.factory('Interceptors', function() {
  var requestFunctions = [];
  return {
    request: function($request) {
      var r = $request;
      for (var i = requestFunctions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        r = requestFunctions[i]($request);
      };
      return $request;
    },
    setRequestFunction: function(fn) {
      requestFunctions.push(fn);
    }
  }
})
```

The factory holds an array of functions, that are called in series. The original request is parsed through the functions. The request is altered in the submodule:

```
angular.module('app.submodule', ['ngResource'])
.run(function($injector,MyService) {
  var Interceptors = $injector.get('Interceptors');
  Interceptors.setRequestFunction(function($request) {
      $request.headers['auth-id'] = MyService.getAuthData().authId;
      $request.headers['auth-token'] = MyService.getAuthData().authToken;
    }
    return $request;
  })
})
```

Also Restangular is worth having a look at. It is a substitution for ngResource and it seems to be possible to register interceptors for Restangular anywhere in the app.